# Am I syntactically wrong in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I have recently written a few sentences for discussion of rhetorical ways in writing. The outcome turned out to be so unexpected that I was blamed for how wrong I syntactically was. So I cordially wish to get an exact answer upon whether I was syntactically wrong. Here are the sentences:

A house was bought by Allen last Sunday.

A house had Allen bought last Sunday.

Allen had a house purchased last Sunday.

Allen made a purchase for house last Sunday.

Last Sunday was the time for Allen to buy his house.

Last Sunday witnessed Allen along his purchase of house.

Buying a house became true for Allen last Sunday.

Thanks for your warmhearted help in the answers. :)

Comment: This is a diverse set of sentences with a diverse range of problems. You are more likely to get an answer if you ask separately about each sentence and, in particular, explain what your rhetorical purpose is.

Comment: Ok, I see you have edited to remove the focus on rhetoric. Syntactically, they are all possible but some are semantically odd and there are various other errors. Again, I recommend explaining what you think may be wrong. And, by the way, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

> A house was bought by Allen last Sunday.

valid (it's using passive and means that Allen bought a house).

> A house had Allen bought last Sunday.

(Not really) valid (the `have someone do something` structure doesn't really make sense, as a house can't do something; it would mean that a house asked someone else to buy Allen for it).

> Allen had a house purchased last Sunday.

valid (it means that Allen didn't by the house himself, but that he had someone else purchase it for him).

> Allen made a purchase for house last Sunday.

Not valid (you don't make a purchase `for` something, and it should be `a house`).

> Last Sunday was the time for Allen to buy his house.

valid (it means that Sunday was a good time for Allen to buy the house, but it doesn't necessarily say that he actually bought it; it could eg end with "But he didn't.")

> Last Sunday witnessed Allen along his purchase of house.

Not valid (`along` doesn't fit here; Something like `Last Sunday witnessed Allen purchase a house` would be grammatically valid, but it would mean that a Sunday saw Allen buy a house, which doesn't make sense (Sundays can't do things)).

> Buying a house became true for Allen last Sunday.

sounds valid, although rather odd (`Last Sunday, the dream of buying a house [...]` would sound better).

Answer (score 0):

Some of this might be - sorry to say - generally described as wooden, dead writing - to a large extent induced by the pervasive use of the passive. Syntax isn't everything.

You may want to read Lectures on Literature by Nabokov and some great writers say Penn Warren (All the King's Men), Pynchon (start with Vineland), Roth or James Dickey (Deliverance), to see what an "alive" style is.

If you're writing fiction, consider joining www.critiquecircle.com to have your work critiqued.

> A house was bought by Allen last Sunday.

This is correct, but brings a strange incantatory lilt to a plain event, which makes the phrase a bit on the poetical side - something to be praised in other contexts. Makes Allen secondary by the use of the passive. More alive still in:

***What a wonderful*** house was bought by Allen last Sunday!

> A house had Allen bought last Sunday.

Nope: suggest the house using other parties/agents to buy Allen:-)

> Allen had a house purchased last Sunday.

Correct, but the construct focuses on "purchased." Variant of dead passive.

> Allen made a purchase for house last Sunday.

Not the intended meaning: it sounds as though he bought an object to be installed in the house, not the house itself.

> Last Sunday was the time for Allen to buy his house.

Correct, sounding too neutral though. Try:

*Last Sunday was the **right** time for Allen to **finally** buy his house.*

> Last Sunday witnessed Allen along his purchase of house.

The "witnessed along" is strangely used.

More alive and personal:

*Last Sunday **we** witnessed Allen **while he /purchased/was purchasing/** a house. That was a show.*

or simpler, but less personal:

*Last Sunday witnessed Allen buying a house.*

> Buying a house became true for Allen last Sunday.

This is correct, and more alive because of "became true."